# stripe integration in react native issue

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to configure stripe in my project,

- Stripe version is: **"@stripe/stripe-react-native":"^0.2.3"**
- I am using this library:  **yarn add @stripe/stripe-react-native.**
- And My project **React native** version is :
  **"react-native":0.65.1"**

Note:

- it works for android but not for IOS
- I am getting the following errors while configuring this

[image]

Provide guidance to resolve this payment issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue and the workaround has been documented on Stripe's React Native Github's README:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native#undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86_64-on-ios

From above guidelines, follow these steps to resolve:

1. Open your project via Xcode, go to project -> build settings, find
   library search paths and remove all swift related entries such as:
   $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME) and
   $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME).
2. Create a new Swift file to the project (File > New > File > Swift),
   give it any name (e.g. Fix.swift) and create a bridging header when
   prompted by Xcode.

Comment: yes, we have already tried these steps, but the first time it worked but when then we were getting so many errors due to conflicts with other libraries,  we are facing version issues, this stripe library creates conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: @HardikVyas are you able to find a solution for this?